# WCF REST web service to accept Stream and list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, .net-4.6

I am building a couple of REST web services with WCF. I have some POST services to which I pass a list of objects in the wrapped HTTP body like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "DoSomething/pages?term={term}",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)
    ]
    MyResponseContainer DoSomethingFromPages(string term, List<Page> pages);
```

This works just fine. I can wrap the `List<Page>` into JSON or XML and put it into the body and it is deserialized automatically.

In a similar way I have another service where I read a binary stream (a file) from the HTTP body like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "DoSomething/upload?term={term}",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)
    ]
    MyResponseContainer DoSomethingUploadFile(Stream httpBody, string term);
```

Now my question is: Can I somehow combine both ways? So basically I want to pass a list of custom objects together with a (file)stream. And I would like to avoid using multi-part forms style.

Thanks a lot!